# open pop up after clicking bookmark link

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am working on a short application. In which I have followiing things.

1. move a link something from my page to Bookmark Toolbar of Browser- **Done.**
2. After clicking on the bookmark link pop should open. (user can be at any other website). he will click on the bookmark link and then pop up should open -- **NOT DONE**
3. that pop should fetch the title,meta,description of parent window (users current opened website).--**DONE**

Obviously My question is about **2 Point**. I cant figure out how to make this bookmark link to an absolute css/javascript so that it can open on any website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [javascript to URLs](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web/jscript/ch10_04.html) like so:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hello');">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Note that I have prepended the URL with `javascript:` to indicate the browser that it should execute the URL as javascript.

So for a pop it would be something like:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://www.example.org');">Bookmarklet</a>
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sms8B/) with the code above for you to test.

For more information about bookmarklets you might like the following article: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/

Comment: You are right, I wasn't reading the question right. Will correct it!