# Bookmarklet Pass Images to Iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html, bookmarklet

I am working on a bookmarklet and very near to finish it.

I got my earlier answer from [open pop up after clicking bookmark link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383917/open-pop-up-after-clicking-bookmark-link). Thanks to Treffynnon.

I have fetched Title, bookmarklet will fetch the current page information. I already fetched the title and passed it to the iframe using query string from js file. But I want to get all the images from the current page and want to show it on my iframe. Is this possible to pass images to the iframe in query string. Will the high size of query string effect it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass the images content with JavaScript.
Possible solutions:

- You can send all image URLs (but if the website doesn't support hotlinking, you won't see them on your website/iframe).
- You can pass the page URL and grab its images by a server script.

Comment: Thank you minras. Getting images from server script is a good way as per my thinking. I will google about this.